# How can data from a GET request be displayed in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch-api

When I click on my button, I expect the data from the endpoint to be returned.

However, I get this error:

```
Id:undefinedURL:undefinedName:undefinedDescription:undefined
```

This is my function:

```
//fetch
function RetrieveEntries(){
    fetch("http://vk-data:8003/v1/entries/", {
headers:{
   'x_auth': 'gdjsjaosh-hkds-dhjsk-hjjdbah',
   'data': 'access-control',
}}
    )
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
})
.then((response) => {
    var results = document.getElementById('results')
    console.log(response)
    response.forEach(element => {
        results.innerHTML = 'Id:' + response.id + 'Type:' + response.type + "Name:" + response.name "<br><br>"

    });
})
.catch(error => console.error(error))

}
```

Comment: Use F12 console to debug your JavaScript and see what’s going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `innerHTML` in every iteration. Did you mean to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to it?

You should also be using the properties from each *element* iteration. Trying to access them on `response` (an array) is why you get `undefined` values.

To format the results, you might want to use something like a [`<dl>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) which can be styled easily with CSS.

```js
const createElement = (tag, ...content) => {
  const el = document.createElement(tag);
  el.append(...content);
  return el;
};

const formatData = ({ id, url, name, description }) =>
  createElement(
    "dl",
    createElement(
      "div",
      createElement("dt", "Id"), 
      createElement("dd", id)
    ),
    createElement(
      "div",
      createElement("dt", "URL"),
      createElement("dd", Object.assign(createElement("a", url), { href: url }))
    ),
    createElement(
      "div",
      createElement("dt", "Description"),
      createElement("dd", description)
    )
  );
```

Then fetch your data, map the array to the formatted elements and append them to the *results* div...

```js
const results = document.getElementById("results");
// empty the <div> for a fresh start
results.innerHTML = "";

fetch("http://vk-data:8003/v1/entries/", {
  headers: {
    x_auth: "gdjsjaosh-hkds-dhjsk-hjjdbah",
    data: "access-control",
  },
})
  .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res)))
  .then((data) => {
    results.append(
      ...data.flatMap((entry) => [
        formatData(entry),
        document.createElement("br"),
        document.createElement("br"), // could also just use CSS margin
      ])
    );
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Fixed now, I missed calling `formatData(entry)`